# Unity: Singleton DontDestoryOnLoad script false reference

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, singleton

So I have this manager in my start scene with DontdesoryOnload, that managers all the UIs, etc. It follows singleton pattern, so if I go to scene 2 and come back to my start-scene, the first manager will remain the same, and the manager in the newly opened start-scene will figure that there's already a manager, and destroy itself.

From here let's call the Manager remains alive Manager-Singleton and the manager that is destroyed as planned Manager-Dead.

The problem I'm having is that the references in my Manager-Singleton seem to false-reference.

When Manager-Dead is destroyed as planned, if I access a public GameObject under my Manager-Singleton, it will show me an error.  Where if I click on those References fields in Inspector, it will lead me to the correct Gameobject which not not destoryed at all.

```
MissingReferenceException: The object of type 'GameObject' has been destroyed, but you are still trying to access it.
```

However, if I avoid Manager-Dead from being destroyed, (So there will be two managers in one scene), the code worked just fine.

I know you might be thinking, if there are two managers in the scene, there might be a UI overlap so that I might be clicking on ManagerDead's Button, and accessing its References. So after I got back to the Start scene, I manually disable the ManagerDead. And it turns out ManagerSingleton is changing ManagerDead's UI !

I really couldn't figure out where it went wrong. Any suggestions would be appreciated.

**Following is some of my codes in case they might be useful:**

```
[RequireComponent(typeof(UIManager))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(DataManager))]
[RequireComponent(typeof(StateManager))]
public class Managers : MonoBehaviour {

    private static UIManager _UIManager;
    public static UIManager UI
    {
        get { return _UIManager; }
    }

    private static DataManager _DataManager;
    public static DataManager Data
    {
        get { return _DataManager; }
    }

    private static StateManager _StateManager;
    public static StateManager State
    {
        get { return _StateManager; }
    }

    public string debugString = "";

    void Awake(){
        //Only one dataControl obj is allowed to exist and pass along. 
        if (GameObject.FindObjectsOfType<Managers> ().Length > 1) {
            Destroy (gameObject);
        } else {
            DontDestroyOnLoad (gameObject);
        }

        _UIManager = GetComponent<UIManager> ();  //!!!!! This is a Singleton class. 
        _DataManager = GetComponent<DataManager> ();
        _StateManager = GetComponent<StateManager> ();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the Component referencing part is what's causing the trouble, Since _UIManager etc is static, that means when component referencing is called in Awake function of Manager-Dead, it will refer those reference to the GameObjects Under it even after it's destroyed.

This results in the static _UIManager from Manager-Singleton will be referred to the Destroyed Gameobjects under Manager-Dead.